# Boost Serialization of class containing mutex member

Tags: c++, serialization, boost, mutex

I am working with a library which defines: a) a "Map" class and b) a "Point" class. These two classes are structured in the following manner:

```
class Point
{
 public:
      Point(const cv::Mat a);
      std::map<cv::Mat*,int> observations;
      .
      .
      .
      std::mutex mMutex;
 }

class Map
{
 public:
      Map();
      std::set<Point*> mapPoints;
      .
      .
      .
      std::mutex mMutex;
 }
```

The program retains a single instance of the map. I want to be able to load/save during application initialization/termination, using Boost serialization. Obviously, the mutex objects cannot be serialized, so I' ll have to manually allocate them AFTER having deserialized/loaded an instance.

To that end, I have defined a default constructor for Point and I have overriden serialize():

```
 namespace boost {
 namespace serialization {
 template<class Archive>
          void serialize(Archive & ar, Point & mapPoint, const unsigned int version)
 {
     ar & mapPoint.observations;
     ... //I do NOT load mMutex
 }


 namespace boost {
 namespace serialization {
 template<class Archive>
          void serialize(Archive & ar, Map & map, const unsigned int version)
 {
     ar & map.mapPoints;
     ... //I do NOT load mMutex
 }
```

The default constructor I have defined for Point actually does nothing, since no member initialization should take place (all values should be loaded from the archive). If the mutex was being dynamically allocated, I would instantiate it inside this default constructor.

The problem is that I cannot replace the stack-allocated mutexes with dynamically allocated ones, because that would require heavy changes to the library. Is there any way out of this, or am I missing/misunderstanding something?

Furthermore, am I correct in not wanting the constructor to do anything when deserializing?

Comment: it's not clear what's your problem

Comment: The problem is the following: how are the mutexes to be allocated/initialized when deserializing? They cannot be saved along with the rest of the class members (since they depend on the OS during runtime). Moreover, is there anything that should be executed within the constructor for proper deserialization?

Comment: just don't (de)serialise them. member of type `mutex` will be automatically constructed using its default constructor, you don't need to do anything

Comment: So, if I understand correctly, any class members which I do not explicitly (de)serialize are automatically allocated and default-initialized during object deserialization? Thank you very much.

Comment: Yes. This is c++ behaviour. Note that you might want to initialize primitive type members in your default constructor. I'd also like to warn about the design smell of having a mutex per `Point` instance. This won't work nicely if you get many points.